# Date Format for API 4.0

Tags: social-tables

When attempting to send an event via post to your api in version 4, I am sending

```
"data"=>
{"id"=>"bfc50100-02eb-11e9-b178-db8890d0b369",
 "name"=>"Name of Event",
   "type"=>nil,
   "description"=>nil,
   "start_epoch"=>1343815200,
   "end_epoch"=>1343869200,
   "archived"=>0,
   "deleted"=>0,
   "is_public"=>0,
   "status"=>"ACTIVE",
   "has_time"=>1,
   "timezone"=>nil,
   "legacy_id"=>nil,
   "created_at"=>"2018-12-18T17:38:36.000Z",
   "updated_at"=>"2018-12-18T17:38:36.000Z",
   "industry"=>nil}}
```

And receiving success from your API, but when going to the url for this event, I am seeing the date formatted as 1/18/70, though in Unix time this should be showing as 8/1/2012.

This occurs with all dates. Am I missing something? Is there another date format you would like? The term epoch led me to believe that you wanted a standard unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send unix time stamp, e.g., `1545326867` - which is in milliseconds